# Dealloc not being called on ARC app with storyboard app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

As I change my rootViewController every time I login and logout from my app.
Suppose ViewController A is rootViewController and after logout ViewController B is assigned as the rootViewController at which point ViewController A's dealloc is not being called. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use Instruments with the Leaks instrument to find out who is maintaining a reference.  It's literally impossible for anyone to tell you without having a copy of the project.